# Plot3D of the mean value of a function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have the following function:

$$f(x,j,G) = -(6.699719\times10^{-6})\times j\times G\times \frac{\sinh(\frac{x}{G})}{
       \cosh(\frac{L}{2G})} $$

where $L=100\times10^{-6}$. I'm trying to plot its average value over $-L/2\leq x\leq L/2$ versus some values of $j$ and $G$. This is my attempt but does seem to be correct:

```
Plot3D[NIntegrate[Abs[-(6.699719*^-6) j G Sinh[x/G]/Cosh[100*^-6/(2 G)]], {x, -50*^-6,50*^-6}]/((50*^-6) - (-50*^-6)), {j, 1*^9, 1*^11}, {G, 1*^-6,10*^-6}]
```

[image]

I get different values in **R**. Any effort is appreciated.

Comment: Capitalization matters in this language;  use `Sinh[]` and `Cosh[]`. Also, why is `L` not specified in your code?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, updated my question.

Comment: What values you are getting in `R`?

Comment: Have you considered rescaling your variables in the meantime? You are dealing with some excessive ranges here.

Comment: @zhk I'm trying to extract same graphs from R. Thanks for asking and your patience.

Comment: @BillDonald You said you got different values in `R`. What are those values? We want to know how those values are in comparison with `MMA`.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ as written at the top of your question is odd in x (basically you're just integrating Sinh), so your mean $f$ vanishes integrating over $-\frac{L}{2} \le x\le \frac{L}{2}$.  Everything else is along for the ride.

The numerical expression you're plotting is averaging `Abs[Sinh[x]]` which **is** even. That's fine and can still be done analytically.

In essence your calculation looks like:

```
meanAbsSinhX[L_, G_] = Integrate[Sqrt[Sinh[x/G]^2], {x, -L/2, L/2}]/L;

meanf[const_, G_, j_, L_] :=  Abs[const j G /Cosh[L/(2 G)]] meanAbsSinhX[L, G]
```

We can compare this with numerical integration on human readable values:

```
 meanf[1, 1, 1, 1] // N
```

> 0.226362

```
NIntegrate[ Abs[Sinh[x]/Cosh[1/2]], {x, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

> 0.226362

And you can reproduce your above plot with:

```
Plot3D[meanf[-(6.699719*10^-6) , g, j, 100*10^-6] // Evaluate, {j, 
  1.*10^9, 1.*10^11}, {g, 1.*10^-6, 10.*10^-6},ColorFunction -> None]
```

I should point out -- I have absolutely no way of knowing whether your numbers make sense, or if this is even the value you want to be plotting.  The good news is your expression isn't very complicated and can be debugged analytically.